# Open local HTML with parameters

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner and I want my code to open a local HTML page with parameters `(e.g. /help/index.html#1)`. Right now I have the below code:

```
def openHelp(self, helpid):
    import subprocess
    import webbrowser
    import sys, os
    directory = os.getcwd()
    if sys.platform == 'darwin': # For macOS
        url = 'file://' + directory + '/help/index.html' + '#{}'.format(str(helpid))
        webbrowser.get().open(url)
    else:
        url = 'help/index.html' + '#{}'.format(str(helpid))
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

The code opens the webpage, however without the parameters `(#helpid)`. Where did I make a mistake? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looked fine to me. I tried it and it worked. You have to call it with openHelp("",1). The #helpid parameter was added correctly. Make sure it is a number.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I have called it with self.openHelp(1) but it does not work. Is it because I'm using Chrome with macOS?

Comment: May I ask the platform you're using?

Comment: I use Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1] and as browser I use: Mac Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit). My operating system is: OSX 10.7.5